# Appium Android pop up

Tags: android, popup, appium

I am trying to automate android application using appium when I launch the application and try to login the pop up asks me to have access to Contacts by tapping on "Allow". The pop up have a different appPackage and it is not part of the application package.

## Locator for the allow button

```
addLocator(Locators.ALLOW_CONTACTS,     "com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button");
```

## method to tap on Allow button

```
Button allowContactsButton() {
        return new Button(getLocator(Locators.ALLOW_CONTACTS));
    }

public void dismissAllowContact() {
        allowContactsButton().tap();
    }
```

The dismiss function does is able to locate the button but does not tap on it

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on autoAcceptAlerts and grant permissions.

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", "true");
```

For location service you will have to explicity set authorization using following:

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("locationServicesAuthorized", "true");
```

You can try similar approach for contacts.

Hoping this helps !